# C - Strange struct behavior in header file

Tags: c

I am newbie in C. I am trying to pack a function `say` to a struct `Person`. It seems fine on single c file. (Console will print "Bye.")

```
// all-in-one-file.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    void (*say)(char *sayType);
} Person;

void person_say(char *sayType);
Person initPerson();

int main()
{
    Person person = initPerson();

    person.say("Bye");

    return 0;
}

void person_say(char *sayType)
{
    if (sayType == "Hi")
    {
        printf("Hi.\n");
    }
    else if (sayType == "Bye")
    {
        printf("Bye.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("...\n");
    }
}

Person initPerson()
{
    Person per;
    per.say = person_say;
    return per;
}
```

However, the console will print "..." when I try to put the struct and function to header file.

```
// person.h

#ifndef _PERSON_H_
#define _PERSON_H_

typedef struct
{
    void (*say)(char *sayType);
} Person;

Person initPerson();

#endif
```

```
// person.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "person.h"

void person_say(char *sayType)
{
    if (sayType == "Hi")
    {
        printf("Hi.\n");
    }
    else if (sayType == "Bye")
    {
        printf("Bye.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("...\n");
    }
}

Person initPerson()
{
    Person per;
    per.say = person_say;
    return per;
}
```

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "person.h"

int main()
{
    Person person = initPerson();

    person.say("Bye");

    return 0;
}
```

I think I have some mistakes in header file or `person.c`. But I cannot find the reason and the solution to fix this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C String Comparison - equates to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593115/c-string-comparison-equates-to-true)

Comment: The question isn't quite the same as yours, but the first answer addresses your exact issue.

Comment: @StephenNewell I read the post and use ```strcmp``` to solve the problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

`sayType == "Hi"` this compares the addresses, not the contents. You should use `strcmp (sayType, "Hi")` for comparing contents of strings.

The explanation why it looks like working when they are all in one `.c` file is this:

When all source is in one translation unit (that is one .c file), compiler mapped string literals with identical contents to the same address. (which is implementation defined behavior that you can not depend). Therefore, identical literals have the same address so that address comparison worked.

However, when compiled in distinct translation units, compiler has no knowledge of other translation unit while compiling one, therefore they are mapped to different addresses.